# Help with google maps link for Iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a google maps link which will open the google map application...@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino"...instead of a specific location i want it to open with the current longitude and latitude..would the link be like @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=ll" like that...or is there a different way to do it?

i am using CLocation framework

Answer (score 2):

You can use different URL parameters to set the location like

> ?center=l,l

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#URL_Parameters

Comment: works...but it doesnt display the current coordinates in the google maps built in app search bar D=